# Spark: how to save pair rdd to json files?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

My Rdd is like:

```
[('f1',1), ('f2',2)]
```

How to save it to json files?

Comment: What is your expected json format?

Answer (score 0):

you can convert rdd to dataframe and write to JSON

```
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

    spark = SparkSession.builder \
        .appName('SO')\
        .getOrCreate()

    sc= spark.sparkContext

    df = sc.parallelize(
        [('f1', 1), ('f2', 2)]).toDF(["key", "value"])


    df.write.format('json').save('output_path')
```

Output in json file looks like below

```
 {"key":"f1","value":1}
 {"key":"f2","value":2}
```